npm override overrides not only the package I specify
I have dependencies structure
├─┬ @nestjs/core@10.4.4
│ └── path-to-regexp@3.3.0
├─┬ @nestjs/platform-express@10.4.4
│ └─┬ express@4.21.0
│   └── path-to-regexp@0.1.10
└─┬ @nestjs/serve-static@4.0.2
  └── path-to-regexp@0.2.5

I need to change @nestjs/serve-static -> path-to-regexp to version 8.0.0
After i add to my package.json
"overrides": {
    "@nestjs/serve-static": {
      "path-to-regexp": "^8.0.0"
    }
  },

i got structure
├─┬ @nestjs/core@10.4.4
│ └── path-to-regexp@3.3.0
├─┬ @nestjs/platform-express@10.4.4
│ └─┬ express@4.21.0
│   └── path-to-regexp@8.2.0 overridden
└─┬ @nestjs/serve-static@4.0.2 overridden
  └── path-to-regexp@8.2.0 overridden

why it override not only nestjs/serve-static dependencies but also nestjs/platform-express -> express ??? how to fix it, because after changes i cant start the project because of changes in nestjs/platform-express -> express
I try different configurations of package.json
I am expecting to get some tip how to fix my problem
